# Uploading a file to MYSQL database

Tags: angularjs, c#-4.0, file-upload

I am developing a website, in which a user can upload a file. I am using angularJS for front end & C# for back end code. I am not sure how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `angularFileUpload` modules to upload files.And inject `$upload` to your controller.
Store the uploaded image files while upload image using creating one scope function `onFileSelect` .And send this array while submit the page.
This is your view file

```
<input type="file" name="files" class="form-control" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" ng-model="files"/>
```

In app.js

```
uploadResult = [];
    $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
        $scope.fileserror = "";
        if($files.length==1){
            var $file = $files[0];
            var mime = $file.type;
            if (mime == '"application/pdf"' || mime == 'image/jpeg' || mime == 'image/bmp' || mime == 'image/gif'){
                var fileSizeKB = parseFloat($file.size/1024);
                var fileSizeMB = parseFloat(fileSizeKB/1000);
                if(fileSizeMB > 5){
                    $scope.fileserror = "You can not upload more than 5mb.";
                    uploadResult = [];
                }else{    
                    $scope.fileserror = "";
                    uploadResult = [];
                    uploadResult.push($file);
                }  
            }else{
                $scope.fileserror = "Only .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .bmp, .pdf files are allowed !";
                uploadResult = [];
            }
        }
    }
```

This is your save function..

```
$scope.saveData = function(resource){
        $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: BASE_URL+'yourUploadedPath',
            method: 'POST',
            params: {},
            file: uploadResult
        }).then(function(response) {
            if(response.data[0].success == 1){
                // success message
            }else{
                // error message                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Raj thanks a lot, if possible can you please help me with C# code for storing this file in db.